# How to control (useEffect ). HOOK

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating a front end for an API in react native. For signed authentication, I use the FireBase service. Everything is good, However, I have a problem. I want after creating the user, my program stays on the login screen and when on the login screen provide the  credential, it should move to the Home screen.

In my case, it navigates to the login screen and then use effect () activate and it navigates to the Home.  How can I stay in HomeScreen?

`// Registrationscreen`

```
const handleSignUp = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword( auth,email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      .then( navigation.dispatch(
        StackActions.replace('Login', {
          user: 'jane',
        })
      ))
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

`//logIn Screen`

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace("Home");
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);  

const handleLogin = () => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      
    
      
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

I wanted that after registration of the new user, it should navigate to the login page and Stay there and when we put in the credential and press logIn then it should navigate to the Home Screen.

Answer (score 1):

There's unfortunately a lot of places this could be going wrong but it looks like there's a pretty serious error in your  LoginScreen component - the useEffect is only running when the component initially renders. This means that by the time the handleLogin function is called the useEffect doesn't know that it needs to run again - which means the redirect to the home screen never runs.

To temporarily fix this: create a user object in state. When the user gets returned from signInWithEmailAndPassword you can store the user into state. Reminder you'd need to update your dependency array in the useEffect to include the user object.